# How unit testing by using Codeception in codeigniter?

Tags: unit-testing, codeigniter, codeception

I have installed Codeception in Codeigniter 2.2 also working fine but how we can load the model in the unit test. I am beginner kindly share me any example related to this.
Thanks.

Comment: codeigniter 2.2 really really old. why are you using it?

Comment: I want to writes unit test in codeignitor. kindly suggest me any package.